# Is it true that given a positive integer $c$, there is at most one solution for $p^a - q^b = c$ where $p, q$ are primes and $p > q$

Tags: number-theory, congruences

Am I correct?

For example:

- The only time $3^a - 2^b = 1$ is $3^2 - 2^3$
- I believe that the only time $2^a - 3^b=1$ is $2^2 - 3^1 = 1$

This is not to say that all $p,q,c$ exist.  Clearly $2^a - 3^b \ne 10$ for all $a,b$.  I am thinking that if a solution exists, there is at most $1$ case where $p^a > q^b$ and at most $2$ if we accept either $q^b > p^a$ or $p^a > q^b$.

Here's my thinking:

- Let $p^a - q^b = c$
- Assume there is a second solution such that $p^d - q^e = p^a - q^b$ and $p^d > p^a$.
- $p^d - q^e = p^a - q^b$
- $p^a(p^{d-a}-1) = q^b(q^{e-b}-1)$
- Clearly, there exists $w$ where gcd$(w,p)=1$ and gcd$(w,q)=1$ and $p^aw = q^{e-b}-1$ and $q^bw = p^{d-a}-1$ and further $p^a \ne p^d \ne p^{d-a}$ and $q^b \ne q^e \ne q^{e-b}$
- So, it follows that $q^{e-b}-p^aw = p^{d-a} - q^bw$ and further that $q^{e-b} + q^bw = p^{d-a}+p^aw$
- Depending on whether $e-b > b$ or $b > e-b$ and whether $d-a > a$ or $a > d-a$, we could get one of the following:

$$q^b(q^{e-2b} + w) = p^a(p^{d-2a} + w)$$
$$q^{e-b}(1 + q^{2b-e}w) = p^{d-a}(1 + p^{2a-d}w)$$
$$\vdots$$

- Now, it seems to me (I haven't completed this yet) that it should be possible to show that $q^{e-2b} \ne q^b \ne q^e \ne q^{e-b} \ne \cdots$ and further that $p^{2a-d} \ne p^{p^a} \ne p^d \ne p^{d-a} \ne \cdots$
- And it seems to me that we can keep doing that ad infinitum where each $p^i < p^d$ and each new power of $p^i$ is distinct from the others.
- This then, if true, would lead to a contradiction since there are at most $d$ distinct powers between $p^d$ and $p$.

Does this make sense?  Is this a well known result?  It there a major flaw in my reasoning?

Thanks very much,

-Larry

---

Edit: Changed the question to make it clearer based on feedback from Tom Collinge.

Comment: This is Catalan's problem which was resolved in 2002. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan's_conjecture

Comment: I thought that Catalan's problem was only true for $p^a - q^b = 1$.  Here's the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_conjecture).

Comment: Sorry I did not pay much attention and missed that $c$. I apologize for my hasty comment.

Comment: Presumably, you mean given c there is only one solution for p and q ?

Comment: @Tom, you are exactly right.  Thanks for the correction.

Comment: Are you excluding $a = b = 1?$.

Comment: @Geoff, I'm not excluding $a=b=1$.  I'm only assuming that $a,b,c > 0$.  Can you provide a counter example where $a=b=1$?

Comment: Well yes, because $3^{1}-2^{1} = 3^{2} - 2^{3} = 1.$

Comment: @Geoff, Very good point!  That's the type of counter example that I was looking for!  Is there also a counter example if we exclude $a=b=1$?

Comment: See my answer for a counterexample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are certainly extra solutions if you allow $a =1 $ or $b = 1$ so I think you might want to exclude these. There is a pretty degenerate one in my comment, but here is a more substantial one: $2^{4} - 3^{1} = 2^{8} - 3^{5} = 13.$

Comment: Thanks very much!  I really like your counter example.